# Is it possible to implement open id connect SSO in ReactJS with IDP independent code?

Tags: reactjs, active-directory, single-sign-on, openid-connect, okta

I have created an SSO in open id connect using Okta as a primary identity provider in a ReactJS and .NET 5 application. The problem is that, for using other Identity Providers like Azure Active Directory, it should be done through configuring in Okta portal. I want to implement it in such a way that the application can be connected to any Identity Provider without getting tied down to one particular Identity Provider. Is this possible? If it's possible please tell me how I should proceed? Any help help is much appreciated.

Please note that I am not looking to simultaneously connect to different identity provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented this using `oidc-client` for the ReactJS application and `IdentityServer4` for the .NET 5 api. If you want to know more about the implementation part, check this article [here.](https://dev.to/tappyy/oidc-authentication-with-react-identity-server-4-3h0d)

For connecting external identity provider to IdentityServer4, you can refer this [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signin_external_providers.html)

Answer (score 2):

The standard pattern is to use an Authorization Server (Okta in your case), then to ensure your apps connect to it using standards based OpenID Connect messages. The AS then manages connections to other providers for you, eg:

- Azure AD
- Social logins
- SAML systems

Your apps then only work with tokens from the AS, and you can fully control claims in APIs and session behaviour in UI clients.

Your apps remain simple and you can change how authentication works by just configuring the AS, with zero code changes.

You should also keep the code in your apps standards based, and you will then be able to switch AS in case ever needed. I tend to do this by using open source libraries instead of vendor specific libraries.

**LIBRARIES**

A couple of years ago [oidc-client](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) was the preferred open source library for SPAs:

- [SPA with Okta](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2)
- [SPA with Azure AD](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.azure)

More recently, browser restrictions have meant there is a trend to move in a `Back end for front end` direction. If you are building something new I would recommend use of this. Unfortunately SPA security is hard:

- [React SPA with Token Handler](https://github.com/curityio/web-oauth-via-bff)

Comment: Could you please tell me what are the open source libraries that you use?

Comment: Added some info above

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I am bit lost at how to implement this on . Net core api.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is to federate the identity providers that you'd like to allow in order to manage your users, scopes, claims etc. from *a single source of truth* - I'll explain a lot below.

This means picking one identity provider as that source of truth (Okta in this example) and connecting auxiliary identity providers to your source-of-truth IdP (connecting Azure AD to Okta as a federated identity provider).

Getting into details, the reason that you want a single source of truth is because each token that is minted and sent to the ReactJS app will need to be validated by the app, in order to be sure that the token(s) came from an authorization server that the app trusts.

On a very granular level, each OIDC `id_token` and `access_token` that your ReactJS app receives has a `iss` (issuer) claim. The tokens are also signed using asymmetric encryption, which allows the token payload to be validated using a public key. This lets your ReactJS app OIDC library verify that the token information came from a trusted source - a source that you've explicitly configured.

***Using multiple primary identity providers means the app would need to be configured to trust multiple `iss` values and fetch public keys from multiple `jwks` endpoints, and this is not a capability that is built into OIDC client library implementations.***

OIDC libraries assume that your tokens come from a single source, and that the `iss` & `aud` claims, and the IdP's `jwks` endpoint (to fetch public keys to validate token signatures) will remain consistent for all user authentications.

Example `id_token` payload from auth0:

```json
{
  "iss": "http://my-domain.auth0.com",
  "sub": "auth0|123456",
  "aud": "my_client_id",
  "exp": 1311281970,
  "iat": 1311280970,
  "name": "Jane Doe",
  "given_name": "Jane",
  "family_name": "Doe",
  "gender": "female",
  "birthdate": "0000-10-31",
  "email": "janedoe@example.com",
  "picture": "http://example.com/janedoe/me.jpg"
}
```

and you can see the public keys that can be used to validate tokens issued by auth servers from my-domain.auth0.com at this endpoint:
https://my-domain.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helped me gain more perspective on this. At the moment I am using Okta's SDK and I am not able to change my primary identity provider or single source of truth to another Identify provider other than Okta. I am not looking to run multiple primary identity provider at once. I want an implementation where primary identity provider can be switched by making changes in the configuration.

Comment: I tried to configure Google as the primary identity provider in Okta's SDK.  I added my localhost url on Google's allowed host list also.  But I was getting CORS error. I am not sure whether I did something wrong or Okta doesn't allow any other identify provider. Do you know whether Okta allows other Identify provider to act as a primary one? I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

Comment: Okta does allow you to add other "social" identity providers, including Google. Their current documentation about this social IdP federation is [here](https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/social-login/#the-social-login-process). Ultimately, if you need to switch the primary source-of-truth, you'll want to use a different OIDC certified "relying party" implementation (not Okta's). [This list](https://openid.net/developers/certified/) has the certified implementations - looks like the npm [oidc-client library](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/) is vendor-agnostic.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that I work for Okta, but I've tried to leave out self-promotion of Okta in my answers here. At the end of the day, you do need to pick one primary IdP to provide tokens for your app. You can add additional IdP's via the admin settings at your primary IdP... this is not something unique to Okta. Even with the `oidc-client` library I linked to above, you're only allowed to configure one IdP for the `UserManager`. Any federation of additional IdP's, such as Google, Facebook, Microsoft, Apple, etc should be done through settings in the IdP dashboard, not in your app.

Comment: Alright. The problem I was having with Okta, is that in order to add an external identity provider I had to make changes in the IdP dashboard. This was causing problems since my client doesn't want to use a dashboard for adding another IdP. The solution was to add IdPs by making changes in the configuration of the project.

Comment: There is a framework called `IdentityServer4` used in .NET APIs. I used `oidc-client` in the front end and `IdentityServer4`  in the backend. In this way, I am able to add IdPs by making configuration changes. The code is still buggy. But I think this can work.